# Deserialize JSON Data by JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm now trying to process some JSON data by using JSON.NET
but i have no idea how to solve it.

The JSON String is very long, so i make it a file [click me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9EkgjS07qCHRGZtTl9pMTN1UTA/view?usp=sharing)

My goal is to deserialize to an array what type is bikeData

```
 public class bikeData
{
    public string sno { get; set; }
    public string sna { get; set; }
    public string sarea { get; set; }
    public string ar { get; set; }
    public string tot { get; set; }
    public string sbi { get; set; }
    public string bemp { get; set; }        
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
    public string mday { get; set; }
    public string sv { get; set; }

    public bikeData()
    { 

    }                
}
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried Google? There are plenty of examples around.

Comment: Did you try and find any solution at all? JSON.NET has [this](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) in its documentation...

Comment: Of course I tried, I'm asking here because i didn't seen this kind of JSON before, maybe I don't get the right keyword to search.

Comment: Can you show your code for deserialization?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, bikeData>>()
```

Comment: oh, this is the point what I'm confuse, now I know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job for you:

```
vara bikeDataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<bikeData>>(jsonString);
```